# Objective C if statement, change scene - ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, cocos2d-iphone

Ok so I'm still on my learning journey and am trying to add a new scene to the end of a game. Currently after a level ends, there is a Next button to take you to the next level. On the final stage, the next button originally didn't do anything and just had a 'return' function. I'm trying to make it so that if the current stage is the last level, the next button (nextAction) will load up the next scene "EndLayer". Here is what I have but it is not working:

```
- (void) nextAction {
    if (g_SoundFlag) {
        [sd_button play];
    }
    _clickedButtonIndex = 1;
    NSInteger currentStage = [AppSettings getCurrentStage];

    if (currentStage >= 24) {
        //return;
        NSString *r = @"CCTransitionFade";
        Class transion = NSClassFromString(r);
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[transion transitionWithDuration:0.3 scene:[EndLayer scene]]];
    }
    [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] removeUnusedTextures];
    [AppSettings setCurrentStage: currentStage+1];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[Game scene]];
}
```

Comment: You don't `return` at the end of that 2nd `if` so the `replaceScene:` method will be called twice; once there, and then immediately after the `if` (at the end).  Is that intentional?

Comment: not intentional, no. I'm a bit unsure how to structure this. Should return be at the end of the 2nd if statement?

Comment: A `return` there would work, yes; it would prevent the 3 statements at the end from occurring.  Alternatively, you could add an `else` and put the last 3 statements in there (then you don't need `return`).